# Iterating through equal time intervals in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, intervals

So I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
> sample
                          userid time_intervals Freq
00008bb4da272a962c275faa085d66d2     2009-01-01    0
00008bb4da272a962c275faa085d66d2     2009-02-01    0
00008bb4da272a962c275faa085d66d2     2009-03-01    0
00008bb4da272a962c275faa085d66d2     2009-04-01    0
00008bb4da272a962c275faa085d66d2     2009-05-01   13
00008bb4da272a962c275faa085d66d2     2009-06-01    0
00008bb4da272a962c275faa085d66d2     2009-07-01    4
```

dput accessible here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d4ccfed8e315e3bc7f3233a7e55512f9

It is a frequency table divided into 35 periods of one month (the same for all users). In other words, every 35 rows, userid shows a new value, and time_intervals starts all over again from 2009-01-01.

Now, I'm having trouble figuring out how to do the following (I have very little experience with data frames): I need to find out the number of consistently active users (where Freq > 0 in all months) across periods of 12 months, starting by 2009-01-01 and moving one month further at each step. I basically need users to have no time_interval with Freq = 0 within the entire period of 12 consecutive months in order to be able to use them in my analyses.

I have the same data in cross tabs format also (don't know which one would be more appropriate to work with):

```
> head(freq_user_month)
                                  time_intervals
userid                             2009-01-01 2009-02-01 2009-03-01 2009-04-01 2009-05-01
  00008bb4da272a962c275faa085d66d2          0          0          0          0          0
  0000bc16c8cd37af06a426da70817b67          0          0          0          0          0
  0000e06e07496624211632e8e264126c          0          0          0          0          0
  0001093b22d1ea8b6615eaf63245347b          0          0          0          0          0
  00010cd7a9e5b6eb882e136f5cd7b4a7          0          0          0          0          0
  00018d018ebf46845eb72194ebb342fc          0          0          0          0          0
```

I hope this explanation is clear enough. Any help on how to begin would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please `dput` your data. You can post it to pastebin and share the link if it's too long. You can also provide a subset or a fake simulation with `fakeR`.

Comment: Add a year variable, group by ID and year, and then subset to groups where `all(Freq > 0)`. The example data isn't really sufficient for a useful answer, though.

Comment: Would this work? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d4ccfed8e315e3bc7f3233a7e55512f9